# Check if an email address is not a "free webmail" (hotmail, yahoo...)

Tags: javascript

Edit: My Website is offering a service to Gmail and Google Apps users only, and do wanted to make sure that others free email users doesn't get an error message when they initiate the oauth pairing.

so here is the deal : either I try to figure out that's a Gmail/Google Apps address, or try to prevent popular free mail users from trying to subscribe.

I want to prevent all "free" email addresses that belongs to Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, etc... from subscribing in my website.

How can I do that correctly in javascript? 
Here a first script I have developped :

```
var domain_matche = /@(.*)$/.exec(email);
var domain_name = domain_matche[1].substring(0, domain_matche[1].indexOf(".", 0))
if (domain_name == "hotmail" || domain_name == "yahoo" ) {
      alert("not a valid email");     
}
```

But it doesn't detect email like test@hotmail.co.il or test@subdomain.hotmail.com.

Could you please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And then I come along, deactivate JavaScript in my browser and register with my GMail account anyway. Your move. :)

Comment: Oh gee. Well, you could just `.indexOf()` against the list you have; does it really matter if the `hotmail` or `yahoo` may exist before the `@`?

Comment: Yeah @TillHelgeHelwig is right, javascript validation is a great way of giving the user a quick response to their form submission, but it should be backed up by server-side validation

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig Already got some fool-proof checkings server side...:)

Comment: You will never cover all free email domains.  There are more than you can possibly discover, plus anyone (especially someone that intends to abuse your site) can create a new one at any time by registering a new domain.

Comment: And for the poor users that only have one of these free email address? A very good way to alienate your users!

Comment: @JaredFarrish. I would say so. hotmail@privatedomain.com shouldn't be blocked, but then no email should be really!

Comment: @Curt - That was somewhat of a rhetorical comment. `;)`

Comment: @EricJ. I know that's impossible to cover all free email, but just wanna cover the most popular

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ha sorry rhetorical comments generally go over my head on a Friday afternoon!

Comment: @Med: I agree with others that this is not a good way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve.  Focus instead on making sure people are real rather than bots, if that's the problem you're really trying to solve.  There are a bunch of "bot detection" questions on SO that have good answers.

Comment: +1 : No need to -1, it is a good question no matter the idea behind it..

Comment: Ok Guys! Thank you all for comments, see my recent edit of the question.

Comment: @LastRoseStudios the website offers a service to GoogleApps and Gmail users only.
PS: I'm a Gmail and Hotmail user

Comment: @Med Then I guess you should point it out CLEARLY on the registration page. But I guess you are right in your approach as people do ignore the writing on the wall and suffer. So look at the code in my answer. It does what you want.

Comment: @danishgoel I should have used "non Gmail/Google Apps" instead of "free mail". thanks for the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, **I would recommend do not do this**. As yahoo does offer a Premium PAID service ( I am using that myself and would be annoyed a lot If you did not allow me to register).

Also you would need to **implement on both client (JS) and Server** (PHP, ASP.net or whatever you are using), as I could easily disable Javascript, and your check would not be executed then.

But if you know what you are doing and want it done properly, Look for first '@' then the following '.' and get the string between them.

Code:

```
// get index of '@'
var index_at = email.indexOf('@');

// get index of the '.' following the '@' and use it to get the real domain name
var domain = email.substring(index_at + 1,  email.indexOf('.', idx));

// now use the domain to filter the mail providers you do not like
```

Code to check all sub-domains (for abc@subdomain.hotmail.com) :

```
// get the string after '@'
var after_at = email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1);

// get all parts split on '.', so for abc@x.y.z you can check both x and y
var dot_split = after_at.split('.');
for(var i = 0; i < dot_split.length; i++)
    // check each dot_split[i] here for forbidden domains
```

Comment: How would that work for a subdomain... test@subdomain.hotmail.com?

Comment: Bryan: Then first look at the '@' and then compare each string between any '.' for 'hotmail', 'yahoo', etc., afterwards :)

Comment: @erizias Sounds like a valid approach, although your code doesn't reflect that approach (you are effectively doing the same thing as the OP).

Comment: @Bryan I have updated my code and it now works as intended, also the original code did work for `test@hotmail.co.il` but not for the subdomain case

Comment: I think I was confusing who was who on this thread, but anyway, looks good now :)

Comment: @Bryan, as you wrote, it wasn't my code, I only recommended a solution for the subdomains :)
danishgoel: well edited :) +1

Answer (score 1):

What Till Helge Helwig means is that you simply **can't do it in JavaScript** or with any client side validation for that matter, you need to validate this on the server.

This regex should match hotmail and yahoo: `[a-zA-Z_-.]+@((hotmail)|(yahoo))\.[a-z]{2,4}` (I just scribbled this regex on the fly so test it thoroughly please)

Answer (score 1):

```
    function submitForm() 
       {
    var email = form.email.value;
    var emailRegex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
    var freeRegex = /^[\w-\.]+@([hotmail+\.]|[yahoo+\.]|[gmail+\.])+[\w-]{2,4}$/;

     if(!email.match(emailRegex)) 
        {
           alert("Please enter a valid email address")
           return false;
        }

     if(email.match(freeRegex))
        {   
           alert("You cannot use free email address!")
           return false;
          }
      return true; 
     }
```

Comment: the freeRegex is incorrect, the [] brackets mean character set, so [yahoo] whould match "hooya" and "yhaoo" and any permutation between the characters

Answer (score 1):

I've been building something like this myself for a client who wants to filter hotmail, yahoo, gmail and other users to different landing pages on his site. I don't ask why, I just do!

In this instance we tell the user we'd prefer a non-free address  to fast track their callback and give them an option to put a different option in.

This is my jQuery version of handling the form, using the info from the above post, especially the regex from @Simeon

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    // Get the email value from the input with an id="email"
    var email_addr = $('#email').val();

    // The regex to check it against
    var re = '[a-zA-Z_\\.-]+@((hotmail)|(yahoo)|(gmail))\\.[a-z]{2,4}';

    // Check if the email matches
    if(email_addr.match(re)){
        // Email is on the filter list
        // Return false and don't submit the form, or do whatever
        return false;
    } else {
        // Email ok
        // Allow the form to be submitted
        return true;
    }
});
```

So, I'm aware that you can turn of javascript and get rid of this, which doesn't matter in our case, as we check server side and do some stuff there, but it's a way to do it so the user doesn't need to wait for a page refresh before being given a message about what we're doing.

I hope that helps someone out!

Comment: Hi @Ben I'm using this validation, But when we type test123@gmail.com Than it's not checking. Please check and update. Thanks