# Check if an email address is a free email service

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting Free Email Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234297/detecting-free-email-addresses)
>   [Check if a an email address is not a “free webmail” (hotmail, yahoo…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271578/check-if-a-an-email-address-is-not-a-free-webmail-hotmail-yahoo)

I already refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271578/check-if-a-an-email-address-is-not-a-free-webmail-hotmail-yahoo) link, but I don't know how to do javascript that validate not only three main free email such as `yahoo`, `hotmail` and `gmail` but also other [free](http://email.about.com/od/freeemailreviews/tp/free_email.htm) email. can anyone help me?

The main purpose is to allow user that have pay email service or company email only send the feedback to our website.

Thank You...

Comment: There are millions of legitimate users that use free email and only have free email (many people I know, for example).  Even if you could reliably detect a free email address (which you can't), why would you want to block all of them from communicating with your site?

Comment: How would JavaScript give you this answer?

Comment: yup..you got a point..but that my request from my boss..which is.. only email that have company name can access to our company data

Comment: Then ask him to get you a list of all company names in the world that he'd like to allow.

Answer (score 0):

There are tens of thousands of free e-mail providers and new ones pop up every day. I doubt you will be able to find a list that will cover more than 5% tops.